# Postgres owner needs usage and select permission separately?

Tags: postgresql

Here is what I did:

Create user:

```
CREATE USER user1 WITH PASSWORD 'userpass';
```

Create database with owner:

```
createdb -U postgres database1  -O user1
```

But the user *user1* cannot run select statements. I have to do:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user1;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO user1;
```

Why it is happening so? Any way to grant all privileges including select to user while creating database. Is owner doesn't mean he can run select queries? How to simplify this? Thanks.

Comment: postgres meant schemas to be owned by user. in that schema owner can create select do whatever relates to the schema orbjects

Comment: So, when I create database with owner, the owner should be able to do all things? No more privileges needed?

Comment: I was talking about schema, not database :) but yes - if you `create database db owner vao;`, vao will create/manipulate any relation